# TSP vs. Word Unscrambler

Tags: complexity-theory

Would the task of outputting whether or not a given scrambled word is a real english word be an equivalent problem to the traveling salesman problem? A well known strategy is to generate all permutations of a given word and compare all of them to all the words in the English dictionary. This algorithm would have a time complexity of `O(N!)`. I could imagine that the two differ in an important aspect: once you find a permutation that matches a word, you can stop generating permutations, whereas with the TSP you have to try out every combination of routes regardless. However, I wrote an algorithm which, instead of generating all permutations of a given word with length *n*, it instead sorts the letters in the given word and performs the same algoritm on the words of the dictionary, then compares the two sorted strings (this method works 100% of the time). My algorithm uses the default Java sort, and after researching, I found that it runs at `O(n log n)`. In total, my program runs at `O(n log n)` because this term grows the largest as n approaches infinity. This algorithm runs in less than polynomial time.
So, if the problems are equivalent, couldn't you use a similar method to solve the TSP problem? How would this relate to P vs. NP?
Sorry if any of this didn't make sense or I wasn't using the terminology correctly, I'm not that experienced in this field

Comment: The fact that you can solve the word scrambling problem in O(n log n) (which BTW is polynomial time) is a clue that the problems aren't equivalent.  If they were equivalent, it would mean that any TSP problem can be turned into a corresponding word scramble problem, which you could then solve in poly-time -- and since TSP has been proven to be NP-hard, this would imply that NP=P, and you would win a million dollars.

Comment: @j_random_hacker that's exactly what I was hoping for lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that there exist algorithms of the same complexity for solving two problems doesn't necessarily mean that the problems have the same complexity, because there could exist more efficient algorithms for one of the problems but not for the other.

The proper way of relating the complexities of different problems is *reduction*: If you can show that any instance of problem *A* can be transformed into an instance of problem *B* in such a way that the answer to the transformed instance is the same as the answer to the original instance, then problem *B* is at least as complex as problem *A* (because the algorithm that solves *B* also can solve *A*). If you can show a reduction in the opposite direction too, *A* and *B* are equally complex.

In your case, there is no currently known way to transform an arbitrary TSP problem to an equivalent unscrambling problem, so it is (to the best of our knowledge) not the case that the problems have the same complexity.

Comment: +1, but TTBOMK "it is not possible" is too strong as it implies that this is a proven fact. I believe all we can say is that no one has yet found a reduction from any NP-hard problem to any problem in P, despite decades of attention from the finest minds in computer science.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You are right (and I was sloppy to gloss over this); I have edited my answer.